# Running Times of Algorithms

Tags: performance, algorithm, runtime

I need to run a segment of code like shown:

```
 sum = 0;
 for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
     for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
         sum++;
```

and find the running times of several values of N and the growth rate associated with those values.

Right now I am using Dev C++ (could use any IDE), but I can't figure out a way to actually display the run times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. Time in the application. For instance, use the `time()` API: http://linux.die.net/man/2/time
2. Time by wrapping your application in another application, that can time runtimes. On *nix systems, there is a handy utility named `time`.
3. Use a stopwatch.